# Which map HTTP APIs are available?

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3

(I asked on programmers.stackexchange.com but my question got voted down into the negative, so I'm re-asking here.)

I'd like to use a map API for a private intranet web site I'm developing.  The Google Maps API is free [as long as the web site that uses it is also free](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1_1).  For private intranet web sites, the Google Maps API costs $10,000 US **per year** (or more) for a business/enterprise license which makes it too expensive for a small 1-guy shop like myself.

So now I'm looking for other options.  Are there any usable HTTP map APIs that are free or lower/reasonable cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google GeoCharts is not a street-by-street level maps and satelite pictures familiar to Google Maps users, but it worked great for what I needed.  You can find it here:  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

(Actually, the entire Google Charts javascript library is quite amazing!)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usagelimits) and [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#tos_commercial) too because what you think about the rules about Google Map is not entirely true. To answer your question, most other providers carry similar license agreement; plus, the solution is not hard to be found hence the voting down (I suppose, no offense).

Anyhow, try Googling **OpenStreetMap**, hope this helps you!

Comment: I think it is pretty explicit:  "if your site meets any of the following criteria you must purchase the appropriate Google Maps API for Business license: [...] Your site is only accessible within your company or on your intranet."